# tsql : outputting each record to their own text file

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

is there a simple way to just output each record in a select statement to write to its own file?

for example, if you have the tsql query in sql server 2005,

```
select top 10 items, names + ':' + address from book
```

and you ended up with 10 text files with the individual name and addresses in each file.

is there a way to do this without writing an extensive spWriteStringToFile procedure?  I'm hoping there is some kind of output setting or something in the select statement.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL returns the result set first, there's no opportunity in there for writing records to specific files until afterwards.

Being SQL Server 2005, it's possible you could use a SQLCLR (.NET 2.0 code) function in a SQL statement without having to make a separate application.

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS, you can do a results to file, but that wouldnt split each record out into its own file. I pretty sure you cannot do this out of the box, so it sounds like you will be rolling your own solution.

Answer (score 1):

You'd do this in some client, be it Java, VBA or SSIS typically.

Comment: i was hoping to avoid using some kind of client.  it looks like i will have to crank this out in vba.